# Can I use Java reflection to get the value of a member that has been added with a Scala macro annotation?

Tags: scala, annotations, scala-macros, scala-macro-paradise

I have a Scala macro annotation that adds a val "x" to a class `MyRecord` at compile time.

I've also got some Java code that uses `MyRecord.class.getDeclaredField(x)` to get the value of the added field.

`javap MyRecord.class` shows that the added field is indeed `public`, yet the Java code throws an error, complaining that it's `private final`.

[Here](https://github.com/julianpeeters/macro-annotation-example/tree/private-final)'s a simplified project showing that Java reflection returns `private final` members.

Since I cannot alter the Java code, how can I get the added field to be seen as `public` by Java reflection?

Thanks,

Julian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field is private, but the getter is public. Even for public vals, scalac doesn't create public fields.